# Flash: pure actionscript project: ToolTipManager class not registered?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a pure ActionScript 3 project that I build using the open source command-line compiler. I'm trying to add tooltips to my controls using mx.managers.ToolTipManager.

The code compiles without issues, but when I try to add the tooltip I get the following exception:

```
No class registered for interface 'mx.managers::IToolTipManager2'
```

I experimented with trying to register a class against that interface manually, something like:

```
var toolTipManagerImpl:Object = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.getDefinition('mx.managers::ToolTipManagerImpl');
Singleton.registerClass("mx.managers::IToolTipManager2", Class( toolTipManagerImpl ) );
```

...but that leaves me with a null ToolTipManager reference.

Any ideas what I have to do to use the ToolTipManager in this environment?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SWCs are not n the build path and, what is more important: it will most likely not work because the whole framework is missing, which the components rely on.

Comment: To clarify -- everything in the "mx" package refers to the Flex framework.  You cannot use the Flex framework classes from a pure AS3 project without some serious hacking (as far as I know, at least) as Florian states.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks for the confirmations.

Comment: meddlingwithfire is right, there were some "experiments" made ... but i wouldn't invest too much time on that. You'd be faster implementing your own tooltip.